# How to prevent a right floated element from dropping down when the browser is resized

Tags: browser, resize, floating

please have a look on the following code segment. Inside the header there is a logo and a navbar(which is floated right). When I resize the browser horizontally, after a certain width, the navbar is coming down and I don't want it to happen. How to prevent the navbar from comming down? Please help

```css
#header
{
 height:150px;
 width:100%;
 background-color:#ff0000;
}
#header #logo
{
 position:relative;
 margin:0;
 top: 50%;
 transform: translateY(-50%);
 margin-left:5%;
}
#header #navbar
{
 list-style:none;
 position:relative;
 display:inline-block;
 float:right;
 top: 50%;
 transform: translateY(-50%);
 margin-right:5%;

}
#header #navbar li
{
 display:table-cell;
 padding-left:20px;
}
#header form
{
 display:inline;
 margin-right:0px;
}
#navbar a
{
 text-decoration:none;
 font-size:20px;
 color:white;
}
#searchbox
{
 height:18px;
 margin-bottom:1.5px;
 width:200px;
}
#submit_button
{
 height:25px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
 <a href="index.html">
  <img id="logo" src=logo.png alt="logo"/>
 </a>
 <ul id="navbar">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contents</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
  <li id="form">
   <form action="">
    <input id="searchbox" type="text" name="Serching" placeholder="Search"/>
    <input id="submit_button" type="submit" value="Go"/>
   </form>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: What does "after a certain width, the navbar is coming down" mean?

Comment: When I go on decreasing the browser window horizontally the navbar is placed below the logo, I want the navbar to remain inline with the logo irrespective of the browser window size.